# Integer is uninitialized in VSCommunity2019,windows10

Tags: c++, for-loop, int, switch-statement, factorial

I am making a calculator in c++ and I have everyting done except factorial which has one issue:
my int number is "uninitialized" this is a console application on vscommunity2019 on windows10 if that helps. Everything works perfect except factorial,when I test it theonly error is the int number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
float n1;
char op;
float n2;
int co;
int i;
int fact = 1;
int number;
calculations: std::cout << "Enter n1!";
    std::cin >> n1;
    std::cout << "\nEnter operator! Here are your choices: + - * / !";
    std::cin >> op;
    std::cout << "\nEnter n2!";
    std::cin >> n2;
    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
        std::cout << n1 + n2;
        break;
case '-':
    std::cout << n1 - n2;
    break;

case '*':
    std::cout << n1 * n2;
    break;

case '/':
    std::cout << n1 / n2;
    break;
case '!':
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    std::cout << number;
    break;
default:
    std::cout << "Error! operator is not correct";
    break;
}
std::cout << "\nWant to continue?Y(type 1)/N(type 0)";
std::cin >> co;
if (co == 1) {

    goto calculations;
}
return 0;


}
```

Comment: What sense does either `for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {` or `std::cout << number;` make when `number` is not determinate (i.e. `int number;` In fact, what is `number` even in the code for *at all* ? I see no code that *ever* assigns a value to that variable, yet several lines that expect one.

Comment: And what stops you from initializing it? I don't understand your question. You already know what the issue is.

Comment: The uninitialised variable is not the only probem. The code calculates the factorial using the `fact` variable, but then prints the answer using the `number` variable. I think the OP is struggling with the basic concept of a variable. This code seems like the OP has found two different pieces of code and cut and pasted them together with really understanding either piece of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, `number` *is* uninitialized.

```
int main()
{
int number; //uninitialized local variable
[...] //no usage of number
case '!':
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) { //first usage of number, before initializing it!
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    std::cout << number;
    break;
[...]
}
```

Luckily you get a *compilation error* and can fix it (thanks MSVC!). For gcc (when trying in compile explorer, it compiles, but I assume there will be a runtime error).

Solution? Probably replace `number` with `n1` in the loop, and output `fact`.

Comment: He knows that number is uninitialized. He mentioned that in his question. This tells him nothing he doesn't already know.

Comment: @Eric, I was assuming he was citing the error message, but did not understand that the number was not uninitialized (thus the quotation marks). I will remove if it is not helpful.

Comment: Besides, it's adding the workaround, which I (maybe incorrectly) assume he does not know.

Comment: Basically, when I see questions like these, I try to remember the level of confusion I had when I was a beginner.